# Groupby in pandas timeseries dataframe choosing most recent event

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas timeseries dataframe that has date set as index and a number of columns (one is cusip).

I want to iterate through the dataframe and create a new dataframe where, for each cusip, I take the most recent data available.

I tried to use groupby:

```
newData = []
for group in df.groupby(df['CUSIP']):
    newData.append(group[group.index == max(group.index)])

'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable


In [374]: df.head()
Out[374]: 
              CUSIP        COLA         COLB       COLC  
date                                                          
1992-05-08    AAA          238         4256      3.523346   
1992-07-13    AAA          234         4677      3.485577   
1992-12-12    BBB          221         5150      3.24
1995-12-12    BBB          254         5150      3.25
1997-12-12    BBB          245         6150      3.25
1998-12-12    CCC          234         5140      3.24145
1999-12-12    CCC          223         5120      3.65145
```

I want:

```
              CUSIP        COLA         COLB       COLC  
date           
1992-07-13    AAA          234         4677      3.485577      
1997-12-12    BBB          245         6150      3.25
1999-12-12    CCC          223         5120      3.65145
```

Should I approach this another way?  Thank you.

Comment: pls post a sample of your dataset and sample output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
           cusip    a     b         c
date                                 
1992-05-08   AAA  238  4256  3.523346
1992-07-13   AAA  234  4677  3.485577
1992-12-12   BBB  221  5150  3.240000
1995-12-12   BBB  254  5150  3.250000
1997-12-12   BBB  245  6150  3.250000
1998-12-12   CCC  234  5140  3.241450
1999-12-12   CCC  223  5120  3.651450

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Sort it

```
In [18]: df = df.sort_index()

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
           cusip    a     b         c
date                                 
1992-05-08   AAA  238  4256  3.523346
1992-07-13   AAA  234  4677  3.485577
1992-12-12   BBB  221  5150  3.240000
1995-12-12   BBB  254  5150  3.250000
1997-12-12   BBB  245  6150  3.250000
1998-12-12   CCC  234  5140  3.241450
1999-12-12   CCC  223  5120  3.651450

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Take the last element from each group

```
In [20]: df.groupby('cusip').last()
Out[20]: 
         a     b         c
cusip                     
AAA    234  4677  3.485577
BBB    245  6150  3.250000
CCC    223  5120  3.651450

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

If you want to keep the date index, reset first, group, then set the index back

```
In [9]: df.reset_index().groupby('cusip').last().reset_index().set_index('date')
Out[9]: 
           cusip    a     b         c
date                                 
1992-07-13   AAA  234  4677  3.485577
1997-12-12   BBB  245  6150  3.250000
1999-12-12   CCC  223  5120  3.651450

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: With this approach, I lost the date.  Do I need to reset index first?

Comment: I would convert to datetime so that you avoid problems when sorting strings (esp. if months/days don't have a leading 0)

Comment: dates these are already datetimes (this is how they display when in an index when times are 0)

Comment: AFAIK, .last() gives last row, but it doesn't sort by any column, So if you have dates in random order, you'll get wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/desktop/test.csv' )
```

convert date to datetime

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

sort dataframe the way you want

```
df = df.sort(['CUSIP','date'], ascending=[True,False]).groupby('CUSIP')
```

define what happens when you aggregate (according to the way you sorted)

```
def return_first(pd_series):
    return pd_series.values[0]
```

make dict to apply same function to all columns

```
agg_dict = {c: return_first for c in df.columns}
```

finally aggregate

```
df = df.agg(agg_dict)
```

EDIT:
converting the date to datetime avoids this kind of error:

```
In [12]: df.sort(['CUSIP','date'],ascending=[True,False])
Out[12]: 
         date CUSIP  COLA  COLB      COLC           date_time

6  1999-12-12   CCC   223  5120  3.651450 1999-12-12 00:00:00
5  1998-12-12   CCC   234  5140  3.241450 1998-12-12 00:00:00
8   1997-12-4   DDD   999  9999  9.999999 1997-12-04 00:00:00
9  1997-12-05   DDD   245  6150  3.250000 1997-12-05 00:00:00
7   1992-07-6   DDD   234  4677  3.485577 1992-07-06 00:00:00
```